# Use tokio::select! to wait for multiple signals fails with a temporary value dropped while borrowed error

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

In a tokio project I want to wait form both `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT`

To just wait for one of the signal works fine:

```
     tracing::debug!("Waiting for the end of the world");
     signal(SignalKind::terminate())?.recv().await;
```

But when I try to use `tokio::select!` from [this answer](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/tokio-how-to-wait-for-multiple-signals/64489/2) in users.rustlang.org

```
use tokio::signal::unix::{signal, SignalKind};
tokio::select! {
    _ = signal(SignalKind::interrupt())?.recv() => println!("SIGINT"),
    _ = signal(SignalKind::terminate())?.recv() => println!("SIGTERM"),
}
println!("terminating the process...");
```

I get an error about a temporary variable being freed while still in use.

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
   --> src/main.rs:495:13
    |
494 |       let ans = tokio::select! {
    |  _______________-
495 | |         _ = signal(SignalKind::interrupt())?.recv() => println!("SIGINT"),
    | |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
496 | |         _ = signal(SignalKind::terminate())?.recv() => println!("SIGTERM"),
497 | |     };
    | |     -
    | |     |
    | |_____temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
    |       borrow might be used here, when `futures` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `(impl futures_util::Future<Output = std::option::Option<()>>, impl futures_util::Future<Output = std::option::Option<()>>)`
```

Is this still the way to do this?

*This question is similar but address a different aspect  [Programmatically create and listen for multiple signals and a ticking interval with tokio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71337098/programmatically-create-and-listen-for-multiple-signals-and-a-ticking-interval-w)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example refereed in the question has a small bug. If the `Result<Signal>` from [`signal`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/signal/unix/fn.signal.html) is handled outside of the `select!` macro there is no temporary variable to outlive its borrowed scope.

```
    println!("Waiting for the end of the world");
    
    let mut sigterm = signal(SignalKind::terminate())?;
    let mut sigint = signal(SignalKind::interrupt())?;

    tokio::select! {
        _ = sigterm.recv() => {println!("SIGTERM Shuting down");},
        _ = sigint.recv() => {println!("SIGINT Shuting down");},
    };
```

Comment: Figured out this wile writing the question hope it could be useful from someone else too.